# CoreNLP Server does not return entity mentions

Tags: stanford-nlp

Having downloaded CoreNLP server from [here](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html) and following [these instruction](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html), when I include `entitymentions` as an annotator:

```
wget --post-data 'Mark Ronson played a concert in New York.' 'localhost:9000/?properties={"tokenize.whitespace": "true", "annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,pos,entitymentions", "outputFormat": "json"}'
```

the returned json is shown below, and although `ner` was added per token, there's no list of mentions.

Any idea why?

(It is worth mentioning that [corenlp.run](http://corenlp.run/) doesn't seem to return them either - seems like the highlights are the results of post-processing).

```
{
    "sentences": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "parse": "SENTENCE_SKIPPED_OR_UNPARSABLE",
            "tokens": [
                {
                    "index": 1,
                    "word": "Mark",
                    "originalText": "Mark",
                    "lemma": "Mark",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 0,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 4,
                    "pos": "NNP",
                    "ner": "PERSON"
                },
                {
                    "index": 2,
                    "word": "Ronson",
                    "originalText": "Ronson",
                    "lemma": "Ronson",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 5,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 11,
                    "pos": "NNP",
                    "ner": "PERSON"
                },
                {
                    "index": 3,
                    "word": "played",
                    "originalText": "played",
                    "lemma": "play",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 12,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 18,
                    "pos": "VBD",
                    "ner": "O"
                },
                {
                    "index": 4,
                    "word": "a",
                    "originalText": "a",
                    "lemma": "a",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 19,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 20,
                    "pos": "DT",
                    "ner": "O"
                },
                {
                    "index": 5,
                    "word": "concert",
                    "originalText": "concert",
                    "lemma": "concert",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 21,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 28,
                    "pos": "NN",
                    "ner": "O"
                },
                {
                    "index": 6,
                    "word": "in",
                    "originalText": "in",
                    "lemma": "in",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 29,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 31,
                    "pos": "IN",
                    "ner": "O"
                },
                {
                    "index": 7,
                    "word": "New",
                    "originalText": "New",
                    "lemma": "New",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 32,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 35,
                    "pos": "NNP",
                    "ner": "LOCATION"
                },
                {
                    "index": 8,
                    "word": "York.",
                    "originalText": "York.",
                    "lemma": "York.",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 36,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 41,
                    "pos": "NNP",
                    "ner": "LOCATION"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For better or worse, we don't currently output the entity mentions to our outputters. The recommended workaround is to post-process the data in the same way the entity mention annotator would: contiguous spans of the same NER are considered an entity mention. I believe all the annotations in the entity mention object are also attached to the component tokens.